# Not able to access a parent class variable from a subclass

Tags: java, casting

I was developing the below program in java with the understanding that two classes Parent and Child, both declaring an instant variable x. Class Parent is
superclass of class Child. An instance (object) of class Child would contain two instances of variable x.

so I have developed the below program

```
class Parent { int x; }
class Child extends Parent { int x; }

class Test {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int y;

        Child c = new Child();// A Child object referenced by a variable of type Child
        y = c.x;    // reference to the x of class Child
        y = ((Parent) c).x;     // reference to the x of class Parent

        Parent p = new Child(); // A Child object referenced by a variable of type Parent
        y = p.x;     // reference to the x of class Parent
        y = ((Child) p).x;    // reference to the x of class Child
    }
}
```

but still the program is throwing compilation problems and not able to access the parent x variable , please advise how to overcome from the same

compilation error i am getting on the line below

```
y = ((Parent) c).x;
```

cannot cast from child to parent

compilation error image:
[image: compilation error image please open]

Comment: You claim you have compilation problems. What does the message say?

Comment: You gave no access modifier to `int x` in the parent class, hence its default access is package private, which means that a subclass cannot access it directly, [read here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).  Making it `protected int x` will probably fix your problems.

Comment: I don't see any compilation problem.

Comment: Those compilation errors are caused by something you don't show in the question.

Comment: The class definition of Parent and Child mentioned in the question is not same  as the actual code. We usually get such errors when the Child class doesn't inherit Parent.

Answer (score 0):

There is not compilation error i found in my eclipse.
I printed output to console as well.

```html
class Parent { int x = 1; }
class Child extends Parent { int x = 2; }

public class Test {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int y;

        Child c = new Child();// A Child object referenced by a variable of type Child
        y = c.x;    // reference to the x of class Child
        y = ((Parent) c).x;     // reference to the x of class Parent

        Parent p = new Child(); // A Child object referenced by a variable of type Parent
        y = p.x;     // reference to the x of class Parent
        y = ((Child) p).x;    // reference to the x of class Child
        
        System.out.println(" child " + y);
        System.out.println( " parent " + y);
    }
}
```

Output :

child 2

parent 2

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the code from your question and got no compilation error. The only scenario i can think of getting this error would be defining Parent and Child classes in different packages and variable x without any access modifier (public) then while accessing x variable you will get the compilation error.

[image]

From the image in your question I cannot see Parent & Child classes defined within the Test class so most likely its the package visibility of variable x that is giving you compilation error.